# Active Model Serializers belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

*This question pertains to AMS 0.8*

I've got two models:

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_combinations
  has_ancestry
end

class UserCombination < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :stage
  belongs_to :subject
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And two serializers:

```
class UserCombinationSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
      attributes :id
      belongs_to :stage
      belongs_to :subject
end

class SubjectSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :description, :subjects

  def include_subjects?
    object.is_root?
  end

  def subjects
    object.subtree
  end
end
```

When a `UserCombination` is serialized, I want to embed the whole subtree of subjects.

When I try to use this setup I get this error:

```
undefined method `belongs_to' for UserCombinationSerializer:Class
```

I tried changing the `UserCombinationSerializer` to this:

```
class UserCombinationSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :subject, :stage
end
```

In this case I get no errors, but the `subject` is serialized in the wrong way - not using the `SubjectSerializer`.

My questions:

1. Shouldn't I be able to use a belongs_to relation in the serializer?
2. If not - how can I get the wanted behaviour - embedding the subject tree using the SubjectSerializer?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This is not really elegant but it seems to be working :

```
class UserCombinationSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :stage_id, :subject_id

  has_one :subject
end
```

*I don't really like calling has_one whereas it's actually a belongs_to association :/*

EDIT: Disregard my comment about has_one/belongs_to ambiguity, the doc is actually pretty clear about it: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails-api/active_model_serializers/frames

Comment: Okay, yeah, this works. I think I understand the `has_one` method better now. In a `Serializer`, the only thing that is interesting is whether a method returns one or many objects. So distinguishing between has_one and belongs_to isn't interesting. It's a kinda suboptimal that the wording coincides with ActiveRecord-terminology, since the terms do not mean the same thing.

Comment: I ran into this same problem just recently. Yes, using the has_one :attribute works for me.

Comment: The documentation for `ActiveModel::Serializer` explictly states: "Serializers are only concerned with multiplicity, and not ownership. belongs_to ActiveRecord associations can be included using has_one in your serializer."

Comment: @awendt May I ask where this is explicitly stated? I can't seem to find that. I'm not saying you are wrong, I am still new to the rails/ruby world and am not too great and quick at finding docs as well as I can with Java. Which leads me to the real point, it isn't explicit if it isn't obvious.

Comment: @Andy I found it there: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails-api/active_model_serializers/frames

Comment: @pjam thanks! Is this where I should expect to find docs for a lot of the third party gem docs for rails?

Comment: @Andy From my experience there's sadly no central location to find documentation. A lot of them have docs on ruby docs, a lot have them on github, and sadly a lot also don't really have any. Most of the time I end up spending a lot of time on google.

Answer (score 6):

In Active Model Serializer 0-10-stable, `belongs_to` is now available.

```
belongs_to :author, serializer: AuthorPreviewSerializer
belongs_to :author, key: :writer
belongs_to :post
belongs_to :blog
def blog
  Blog.new(id: 999, name: 'Custom blog')
end
```

https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/0-10-stable/docs/general/serializers.md#belongs_to

So you could do:

```
class UserCombinationSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id
  belongs_to :stage, serializer: StageSerializer
  belongs_to :subject, serializer: SubjectSerializer
end
```

Answer (score 4):

What if you try with something like this:

```
class UserCombinationSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :subject,
             :stage,
             :id

  def subject
    SubjectSerializer.new(object.subject, { root: false } )
  end

  def stage
    StageSerializer.new(object.stage, { root: false } )
  end
end
```