# Active model serializer association unless object.user == current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers, rails-api

I have a User model and an Employment model like so:

```
Class User
 has_many :employments

Class Employment
 belongs_to :user
```

I'm serving up a JSON api via [Active model serializer](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) like so:

```
class EmploymentSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id
  has_one :user

class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id
```

Everything works as it should. Here's the problem:

When the current_user is an employer, I'd load the employments with the user associations, which works fine. When the current_user is *not* an employer, I want to load the employments *belonging* to the user.

As the EmploymentSerializer has_one :user, this results in a recursive query where the current_user has_one employment has_one current_user ad infinitum.

I've tried adding this method in the EmploymentSerializer but it doesn't work:

```
def include_user?
  object.user != scope
end
```

How do I load the current_user's employments?

---

**Solution**

The recursion was caused by another serializer, and this question is irrelevant. AMS works as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `belongs_to`, the table accepts the responsibility for the foreign key. With `has_one`, the table expect the other table to hold it. Since your `Employments` table has the foreign key to the `Users` table, `has_one :user` in the serializer doesn't make sense because it assumes that the `Users` table has the foreign key to the `Employments` table.

Generally, the serializer relationships should usually mirror the model, and you are mixing them up here. When your `Employment` class has a `belongs_to :user` relationship, your serializer should have the same one and not the opposite `has_one` relationship.

**Edit:**
Ryan.lee's comment is correct. In `active_model_serializers`, `has_one` is indeed the same as `belongs_to` because serializers are concerned about multiplicity and now ownership. But since this is quite confusing because ActiveRecord, version 0.9 adds support for `belongs_to` too to mirror the ActiveRecord associations. So, using `has_one` in the serializer when the model has a `belongs_to` is indeed correct, but I would suggest to also use `belongs_to` in the serializer to avoid confusion since they [mean the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13125214/active-model-serializers-belongs-to) in the context of the serializer (but [not ActiveRecord!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808926/whats-the-difference-between-belongs-to-and-has-one))

Comment: AMS has_one indicates multiplicity and not ownership. It simply tells AMS which records to fetch. It is not the same as the Activerecord has_one relationship.

Comment: Which version of AMS are you using?

Comment: 0.10.0.rc1. As it turns out, the recursion was caused by another serializer, so I'll delete this question. Thanks for trying to help!